# Git push changes made via filter-branch

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I cut the history of my `master` branch into an `old_stuff` branch, via the advice of this Q&A: [How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository) . To save you a click-through, the process involves grafting the last commit of `master` to the root commit, effectively giving it no parent, then using `git filter-branch` to make that change permanent. My local repository is now how it should be, with a short `master` branch and a long history branch.

But if I `git clone` the repository, that commit that shouldn't have a parent has the same parent as before. When I do `git push -f origin master`, I wind up with a `master` branch with the newly created commit at its head, but with a parent of the prior commit to `master`. So now I have a long `old_stuff` branch and a `master` branch that is as long plus one commit. If it's relevant, the remote is on Github.

How do I tell the remote repository and other copies to revise the parent for the new commit?

PS: I've read the warnings about how changing the history at a shared repository breaks other people's copies. I know the names of the people involved and can ask them to accommodate, so I'm comfortable revising the branch history in this current case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I tell the remote repository and other copies to revise the parent for the new commit?

You.... can't do that.  If you change the parent of a commit, you're changing that commit, with everything that goes along with that (new sha1, etc).  It might be more helpful to think of the "parent" as a "child", in terms of which way the pointers are pointing.

It sounds like you're trying to get your history down to one commit.  If that's the case, then checkout (heh) `git checkout --orphan`.  Once you've done that, it's a matter of pointing your master at it (`git reset --hard <new orphan branch>` while on master) and a forced push to origin.

Any work your compatriots have done will need to be replayed on top of this new master; `cherry-pick` will help there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my situation, and with a lot less fuss than the grafting and filtering method.