# To (sub)clone / create only part of original repo / starting only from specific commit / sha

Tags: git, git-clone

Is it possible to only clone (i put in title "sub" clone to highlight specifically I do not want to clone entire repo) parts of the repo, from very specific commit / sha?   Or, from the start of only very specific one branch, ignoring entirely everything else *including* all history of changes leading upto the branch (or fixed sha), and only keep history/changes from that specific sha or branch start?

If not 'clone', how would I say, only take a very minor sub-set of recent changes I'm interested in, *with* accompanying log  [i.e., exporting with git archive won't cut it, as I understand it throws all log entirely ]  ignoring all rest (which can have 100 of thousands of commits .. )

And not sub-directory only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git shallow clone to specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932389/git-shallow-clone-to-specific-tag)

Comment: The suggested thread on shallow clone mostly answers it.  I just don't like the --depth argument: I would prefer some way to specify "from the start of this branch, take all the branch commits" .  Instead of manually counting them.   One can also use --shallow-since=<date> , which is also kinda, sub-optimal imho...     As I cannot comment on answers (low reputation) of others, I have to keep my comments here, see if anyone else throws something.. Thanks to @melpomene

Comment: ok so seems with shallow since date is probably my best bet here; also --single-branch