# How to do I get a log of changes from Bitbucket (like `git log`) but without cloning the repo?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am looking to run the command `git log --since="2 weeks ago" --stat --oneline` on a git repository without requiring the clone. I am attempting to track changes made over a time period (using since) down to the specific files to commit.

The by commit is not required but, it is a nice to have. I would prefer to not clone down each repository so interfacing with the Bitbucket API would be optimal. I do have physical access to the git repositories. If required I could use the `--git-dir` command.

Comment: git commands ONLY work within an actual git repository, whether you get that by `git clone` or copy the full repository directory (including the git database, the `.git` folder). Removing the `git` tag because this isn't a git issue. I have no idea if what you want from the  "Bitbucket API" makes sense. I've edited the title in an atempt to make sense of your request. If it's wrong please clarify what you have and want.

Comment: I looked into the API for Bitbucket but, I was not exactly i didn't see anything that exactly fit the bill.

Comment: Then I believe you are out of luck, my friend. But why not just do the clone? You can look into doing a shallow/sparse/parttal clone if you are worried about size. I've never done it but do a search. Here a few I found for you quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526540/shallow-and-sparse-git-repository-clone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git/9920956#9920956 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932389/git-shallow-clone-to-specific-tag