# How to reduce disk space usage in a large repository?

Tags: git, disk

I have a git repository with about 1 year of development history, and it is already 37GB. How can I minimize the size in a way where I will delete the old history? That is, I only need the history that covers the last 2 months, others can be removed.

Comment: How large is the `.git` directory?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra Hello Sir. The .git directory is about 35G.

Comment: 37G?! I think you have added the executables, movies, photos... IMHO, it is a bad practice, you shall add just the files you need (for test, maybe one or 2 multimedia files)

Comment: Yes, I think that too. It's very rare that your piece of code comprises of 35GB. 1 GB is rare. Have you accidentally commited some large file which is not required? You can also sort the files with size and see are there unnecessary files on the top?

Comment: @sop yes, it is 37G , since my repository is database tables

Comment: @HimanshuMishra yes, it is 37G , since my repository is database tables

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three main options are:

- removing large files from the history ([with, for instance, BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/))
- [split a repo subfolder into its own repo](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)
- split a repo history (starting with a new repo from HEAD of new repo, keeping the old one for archive).

On the last point, see "[How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4515580/6309)", using a script like this one (with the SHA1 of the commit from 2 months ago, as a parameter)

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout --orphan temp $1
git commit -m "Truncated history"
git rebase --onto temp $1 master
git branch -D temp

# The following 2 commands are optional - they keep your git repo in good shape.
git prune --progress # delete all the objects w/o references
git gc --aggressive # aggressively collect garbage; may take a lot of time on large repos
```

Since it rewrites the history, you will need a `git push --force`.
Since the OP is pushing to `git.assembla.com` ([see discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83378/discussion-between-rkevx21-and-vonc)), [this issue clearly states](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets/5848-rejected-remote-master-branch-removal-operation--cannot-set-receive-denydeletecurrent-to-ignore?comment=694952743#comment:694952743)

> You need to enable the `--force` option.
> This is done from the **Git repository Settings tab**. You need to be an 'Owner' on the space to see the settings tab.

Comment: I save the shell script as git-remove-history.sh, how can I execute it sir ? 
       bash git-remove-history.sh ?

Comment: @rkevx21 what version of Git are you using. What OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) are you using (at which version)

Comment: @rkevx21 What version of Linux (type `uname -a`) and with what version of Git? (type `git --version`)

Comment: Linux rkevx21 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @rkevx21 Ok. A simple `./git-remove-history.sh <SHA1>` should be enoough (make sure you have your repo backed up first, or simply available in a Git repo hosting server somewhere before doing that). Replace `<SHA1>` with the SHA1 of the commit from which you want to start your history (the one commit which is two months old)

Comment: ah.. so it means that the <SHA1> is the commit id ?

Comment: @rkevx21 the commit id of the commit from which you want to keep the history.

Comment: I have this message

WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

Comment: @rkevx21 the master should reflect the new history (a git log should only show the last commits)

Comment: sir , when I run the script, it works, but my problem now is how can I push it to the repository, since it will give you a message to pull first before I can push.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83378/discussion-between-rkevx21-and-vonc).

Comment: @rke It rewrites the history of the repo, so you need a Git mush --force.