# Huge GIT repository - what can I do?

Tags: git, github

My GIT has turned into a monster. It takes almost 70 minutes to clone it.
Is it possible to trim the repository and archive old commits that are no longer relevant? I don't want to delete them though.
What can I do to minimize the size of my git repository?

Comment: Are you storing binary files in the repository or only code files?

Comment: Size and cloning method would help.

Answer (score 0):

See "[How to reduce disk space usage in a large repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424082/6309)" for the main options.

In your case, I would advise to split a repo history, but also check if you can [split some of the subfolders into their own git repos](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) (and reference them through submodule [gitlink entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)).

Make sure that no binaries (especially if they can be re-generated from the sources) are stored in the repo history.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from getting rid of unnecessary files from the repository as VonC pointed out, there are two possibilities that come to my mind:
- First one would be to clone only the necessary branches, since git 1.7.10 you could do something like:

```
git clone URL --branch branch_name --single-branch [folder]
```

This could be useful if you have many branches and divergences in your repository, otherwise there won't be much gain.
- An alternative to this would be a shallow-clone, which basically is a partial clone of your repository. You could use it like this:

```
git clone --depth [depth] remote-url
```

There were many limitations with shallow-clone as not being able to fetch or push to the repository, but apparently some of them have been overcomed in [1.9 version](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7648573).
You could also use the [filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) option to rewrite some history but that would mean a lot of manual effort if your repository is very big, and everybody would need to clone repo again once you are done with it.