# Make a special version of a corporate repository public

Tags: git, git-remote

We have an internal, corporate repository that I would like to make public, but with all internal information removed (like credentials, internal company structures, etc).

How can I achieve this? When I create a branch, it will contain the entire history. Basically I want to keep the two in sync, but still keep the public repository clean of any critical information.

Is this doable with a branch of some sort? I tried around a bit, but it always keeps pushing the complete history (which kind of makes sense).

The problem is: Currently, critical information is in the history. If I remove that in a commit, the removal will be part of the public history.

Basically, I want the "public" branch to start at a certain point of the actual history, without including any parents, but in the future follow the same history... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say create a `graft` for your "starting point" and then it should be seemless possible to go ahead with a normal branch:

see:

- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint
- [How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository#4909248)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Trying to push that into our corporate repository results in "missing necessary objects"?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I don't know why you getting the "missing necessary objects" message. 

But the general workflow is: 
  1. clone your existing repo 
  2. make a new commit to the cloned repo. 
  3. take the new commit id and add them to `.git/info/grafts` on the new clone 
4. check wath you have done with git log