# Remove history from huge Git repository

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm currently trying to **reduce** the **size** of my **Git repository** but faced many issues.

**Introduction**

I have a huge and complex Git repository containing thousands of commits and more than ten branches. It's current size is over 2 GB.

**What I want to do**

I would like to **clean the repository history** in order to reduce its size as much as possible. I chose a special commit that I want to be my **new root commit** (call it `<NEW_ROOT>`); I want to **remove every commit before** `<NEW_ROOT>` and **keep** all the commits **after**.

I want to **keep** only `master` and, possibly, `develop` **branches**, any other branch should be removed from history to reduce size.

At the end of the procedure I want to **push everything to remote**, so that it only keeps updated master and origin (basically it must reflect my local situation).

**What I tried so far**

I browsed the web a lot and found many solutions, but none of them worked for me. In particular I guess that [such a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953383/1133284) would be perfect in my case, unfortunately I got a lot of **conflicts when rebasing**.

I also struggled a lot because many solutions I found refers to **obsolete and deprecated tools/options** (e.g. `git filter-branch`).

Could you please help me find a way out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like something you can achieve by doing a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_shallow_repository) of your local large repository:

> A shallow repository has an incomplete history some of whose commits have parents cauterized away. [...] This is sometimes useful when you are interested only in the recent history of a project even though the real history recorded in the upstream is much larger.

The idea is to shallow clone your local repository into a new directory *starting* from the commit you deemed to be the new root. Note that this solution assumes that you're only interested in keeping a *single branch* in the new repository (e.g. `master`).

The first thing you need to do is create a branch reference that points to the *parent* of `<NEW_ROOT>` in the existing repository:

```
cd your-large-repo
git branch new-root <NEW_ROOT>^
```

We'll use `new-root` as the *cut off* point for the shallow clone. Since we do want to include `<NEW_ROOT>` in the new repository, we set the cut-off point to its parent. Of course, `<NEW_ROOT>` must be *reachable* from `master`.

At this point, you can go ahead and clone your *local* repository into a new directory specifying that:

1. You're only interested in the `master` branch
2. You want to *exclude* all the commits reachable from `new-root`

Here's the complete command:

```
git clone --branch master --shallow-exclude=new-root file://C:\path\to\your-large-repo C:\path\to\your-new-repo
```

The [`--shallow-exclude`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---shallow-excludeltrevisiongt) option is what tells Git to exclude all commits leading up to and including `new-root` from the clone.

Now, if you `cd` into `your-new-repo`, you'll find that it only contains the `master` branch and that the root commit is `<NEW_ROOT>`.

The new repository will have its `origin` set to `file://C:\path\to\your-large-repo`. So, before you go any further, you'll have to replace it with the actual URL of the remote repository:

```
git remote set-url origin https://example.com/your-large-repo.git
```

At this point, you can simply *force push* the new history to the remote repository (with the usual caveat on the [consequences of force pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repository)).

Comment: Finally a working solution, thanks a lot!!!
I tried to use a shallow copy but it didn't work because the "server doesn't support shallow copies". I didn't realize I could achieve the same by using the local repository, now I almost halved the size. Thanks! :-)