# How to clean a secret key in all GitLab history?

Tags: gitlab

My team have a project that use some secret keys. Six months ago we have merged a lot merge requests with all secret keys in code.
Now I clean my branch master and put every key in .env, however all keys can be found in gitlab history.

Can I clear all of the history keys automatically or should I clear manually?

Comment: I expect a better solution will be to change your keys.

Comment: Yes, yes, it's ocurried with few keys. I think that is the best option for me if I can't have other option .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the old git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953300/how-to-delete-the-old-git-history)