# How to truncate git history before a specific commit?

Tags: git

Having all binary files added to my git history by mistake, I have a git repo of size about 50 MB. How can I remove all commits before a specific commit from history? For example having following history, I want to remove all commits  before C2 as if C2 was first commit. (Actually C2 may be a merge commit)

I already tried [git-filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository) which simply doesn't do what I need,  and [this](http://bogdan.org.ua/2011/03/28/how-to-truncate-git-history-sample-script-included.html) script which seems to be quiet popular, though it removes entire history; leaving a single commit.

[image: History]

Comment: `git rebase -i` and then remove C1

Comment: Side-question: May I ask how you created that illustration?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: He took it from the git-scm site. But I can recommend using [this](https://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/) smart tool or [gitgraph](http://gitgraphjs.com)

Comment: @sorush-r: how many branches and how many commits do you have on top of C1 ?

Comment: If your question was answered please consider accepting to, if not consider providing more information to help us help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use `git filter-branch --parent-filter`, and drop C1 from the set of parents.

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter "sed -e 's/-p $(git rev-parse C1)//'" -- --all
```

`$(git rev-parse C1)` is used to get the full 40-character commit ID, and can be replaced if you already know what it is.

If some of `C1`'s ancestors are being pulled in via merges or so on, you can also drop them in the same way, or use a more complex script like

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter '
    for i in $(cat); do
        if [[ $i = -* ]] || git merge-base --is-ancestor "$i" C1; then
            continue
        else
            echo -n " -p $i"
        fi
    done
' -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a new orphan branch with cherry-picking afterwards.

That way you can check everything and maybe even leave the old state as a backup on your machine.

---

To start things off create a new branch at the point of `C2`

```
$ git checkout <Hash of C2>
$ git checkout --orphan new-master
```

[`git checkout --orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt) will create a new branch with no parents.

At this point add or remove files as you like with

- `git add` Add files for this new first commit
- `git rm --cached` Remove files for the new first commit but leave them on the hard drive
- `git rm` Delete files for the first commit as well as from the hard drive

Make sure that all files are present that are going to be changed by later commits, otherwise the cherry-picking might get very messy.

Now `git commit` to get your new initial commit ready.

Last but not least *simply* reapply all the other commits by [`cherry-picking`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#git-cherry-pick-codegitcherry-pickHEADmastercode) the correct ranges.

```
$ git branch new-starting-point # for future reference
$ git cherry-pick ^C2 master
```

And repeat these steps for all the other branches that need a new history.

```
$ git checkout -b new-server new-starting-point
$ git cherry-pick ^C2 server
```

---

If you want to check for correctness you might want to do some `git diff master new-master`.

To clear space delete **all** old branches (so that the old commits are not reachable anymore). At the following step you might lose data. Be sure you still have everything you want: A `git gc` should be all you need to clear space.

Comment: Cherry-picking (and rebasing) doesn't preserve anything other than a linear history - you'll have to manually deal with merges, if you want them in the 
new history.

Comment: @ephemient you are completely right. If the history after your new start commit has merges `cherry-picking` is no real option. It would be cleaner to use `filter-branch`. If you expand your answer and explain the options I will happily upvote it

Answer (score -1):

Using `git filter-branch`, rather than erasing the whole commit, you can remove the binary files from the commit :

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -rf bin/ && git rm --cached -f ./a.out' -- --all
```