# How to remove all git origin and local tags?

Tags: git, tags, removeall

How do you remove a git tag that has already been pushed?
Delete all git remote (origin) tags and Delete all git local tags.

Answer (score 492, accepted):

1. Delete All local tags. (Optional Recommended)

   ```bash
   # Clears out all your local 
   git tag -d $(git tag -l)
   ```
2. Fetch remote All tags. (Optional Recommended)

   ```bash
   # All remote tags give you a complete list of remote tags locally
   git fetch
   ```
3. Delete All remote tags.

   ```bash
   # Note: pushing once should be faster than multiple times
   # Deletes the remote tags concerning the local
   git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)
   ```
4. Delete All local tags.

   ```bash
   # Deletes the local tags after fetch 
   git tag -d $(git tag -l)
   ```

Comment: If you got error message "argument list too long", which you probably would if you're trying to clear tags
Use `git tag -d $(git tag -l | head 100)`

Comment: What's the difference between option 1 and 4? They are both `git tag -d $(git tag -l)`.

Comment: 1) clears out all your local tags 2) retrieves all remote tags giving you a complete list of remote tags locally 3) deletes the remote tags with reference to the local list 4) deletes the local tags from step 2

Comment: minor fix for head syntax `git tag -d $(git tag -l | head -n 100)`

Comment: I think on **3.** it should be `git push --delete origin  $(git tag -l)`

Comment: `git tag -d $(git tag -l)` fails on git 2.23 with ```error: switch `l' is incompatible with --delete```

Comment: I had 90K local tags, so using `head` was not acceptable, the syntax that worked for me was `git tag -l | xargs -L1 git tag --delete`

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but I had some tags on `remote` that didn't `fetch` to local for some reason. I had to do `git fetch --tags --force` in lieu of step 2, and that worked.

Comment: Same as @turbanoff, 3rd step didn't work. I end up pushing those changes and it worked

Comment: For remote tags it would be better to `tags="$(git tag -l)" && test -n "$tags" && printf " :refs/tags/%s " $tags | xargs git push origin` in case any tag has the same name as some branch [reference](https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-local-and-remote-tags-on-git)

Comment: on windows Powershell i had this issue `git tag -d $(git tag -l) fails on git 2.23 with error: switch `l'` i run it with wsl  or git-bash and it worked

Comment: `git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)` failed for me with error `fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs` since `git tag` showed no local tags for me. So, I had to delete the remote tags **manually.** [Here's how I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71598448/4561887).

Comment: I got `error: switch `l' : incompatible with --delete`

Comment: If you have a ton of tags, skip step 1. Complete waste of time.

Comment: This won't always work because if you have local tags which no longer point to valid objects, then `git tag -l` will not print any of the ok tags and will just print errors for the bad tags rather than listing them: `error: refs/tags/badtag does not point to a valid object!`  Is there some porcelain command that will list all tags without throwing these errors for the bad ones?

Answer (score 21):

For windows using command prompt:

Deleting local tags:

```bash
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('git tag -l') do git tag -d %a
```

Deleting remote tags:

```bash
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('git tag -l') do git push --delete origin %a
```

Comment: When using PS: `git tag -l | %{git tag -d $_}`

Comment: For local tags: git tag -l | xargs git tag -d

Comment: @LongTP5 - `xargs` is not native windows command and should be installed additionaly.

Comment: Wow, works, but isn't fast at all! About 5 dels per second on local trags deleting.

Answer (score 7):

The [main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702758/4561887) didn't work for me.

This failed:

```sh
git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)
```

Error:

> ```
> fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs
> ```

That's because *I had NO local tags!*

`git tag -l` showed *nothing*, even after running `git fetch` to supposedly fetch all remote tags!

BUT, the following *worked!:*

Under certain, rare circumstances, where you have remote tags on GitHub but no local tags, for instance, you may need to *manually* specify the tags to delete.

Go to https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME/tags (ex: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/sublime_gcode/tags) to view all remote tags.

Mine showed tags `1.0.0` and `1.0.1`. Delete them manually with:

To **delete remote tags** manually:

```sh
# General format to delete a **remote** tag on remote named "origin"
git push --delete origin <tag_name>

# My case exactly
git push --delete origin 1.0.0
git push --delete origin 1.0.1
```

To **delete local tags** manually:

```sh
# list all tags
git tag
# OR (same thing): 
git tag -l

# delete a local tag
git tag -d <tag_name>
# Example: delete local tag named `1.0.0`
git tag -d 1.0.0
```

Source where I learned all of this: https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-local-and-remote-tags-on-git/

Comment: I'm just getting "remote: Repository not found fatal: repository 'https://...git not found" which seems odd, as via IntelliJ it is working

Comment: Should execute fetch force before:
`git fetch --tags --force`