# How can I add a project from Github to Github without the commits?

Tags: git, github, commit

I have this project already on Github, but I want to share it again, without the commits. If I try to do it from the IDE, the commits will remain, and if I try to upload it manually, I can't because there are too many files. What would be a work-around for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you change which commit is the root commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68461500/can-you-change-which-commit-is-the-root-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start a new, empty repository on github
2. Clone it to your machine
3. Put all your files in it
4. Commit and push