# How do you delete old commits?

Tags: git

I have big project, created for 5 years. I would like remove old commits, for example over 2 years. The whole code should be intact, but the first one commit should be the one from 2 years ago.

Comment: You can create a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---shallow-sinceltdategt) of the repo and remove the old one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: But still, why do you wish to remove the commits in the first place?