# How do you pass build server credentials to access an Azure DevOps repo?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My use case is I want to create a shallow clone using [`shallow-since`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---shallow-sinceltdategt) as noted in [How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository)

However, [`checkout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) does not provide that option.

My assumption would be to do a

```
- checkout: none
- bash: |
    git clone $(Build.Repository.Uri) \
      --shallow-since 2020-01-01 \
      $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

But I am not sure where to put the credentials. The variables I can probably look up.

I've added a [feature request for `checkout`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Provide-a-way-of-making-checkout-a-shall/1427995?space=21&q=Provide+a+way+of+making+checkout+a+shallow+clone+by+date&entry=myfeedback) so I won't need a workaround in the future.

I am suspecting it is something with `System.AccessToken`

Comment: Thanks to the answer I got it to the point where it shows At present Git used in Azure Devops does not support `shallow-since` as noted by this error message

```
fatal: Server does not support --shallow-since
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Inject your [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) in the clone url:

  ```
  https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}
  ```
- Inject the System Access Token in the clone url:

  ```
  https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using URL manipulation, I use header modification.  This avoids using `sed`

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout: none
  - bash: |
      git clone $(Build.Repository.Uri) \
        -c http.extraheader="Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" \
        --single-branch \
        --no-tags \
         $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      # --shallow-since 2020-01-01
```

Unfortunately, Azure DevOps does not support `--shallow-since` as of this writing.