# How to clean up old commits in git?

Tags: git

I have a GitHub repo that contains a lot of commits. I would like to remove all commits, so that only the last 20 commits or so are left. But, since I'm quite new to git, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Why would you want to lose all the history? What's the benefit in removing those comits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the old history from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: Though, to be fair, the answers on that question all don't mention the currently recommended tool for operations like this, [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/).

Comment: It's a fair question. Even if the answer is "don't do it".

Comment: I would do it with a new repo (and archive the old one). A) Clone your repo with `--depth=10` and upload it to a new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your main branch is `main`. And suppose the SHA of the commit that you want to turn into the first commit is `123456`. Then

```
git checkout --orphan temp 123456 
git commit -m 'new initial'
git rebase --onto temp 123455 main
git branch -D temp
```

For example, suppose I have

```
* a894910 (HEAD -> main) cc
* 045900f bb
* 35184b3 aa
* 4465ea9 X
* 62155b4 E
* 5a8cc3a A
... thousands more commits ...
```

And suppose I want to snip this history after the commit whose message is `X`. Its SHA is `4465ea9`. So I say:

```
% git checkout --orphan temp 4465ea9
% git commit -m "new init"
% git rebase --onto temp 4465ea9 main
% git branch -D temp
```

The result is:

```
* 2ca92d4 (HEAD -> main) cc
* fb1904d bb
* 7ebe96e aa
* cba7eb2 new init
```

The SHA numbers have all changed, but these are copies of the desired commits.

Finally, the easiest and safest way forward is to create a new remote repo at GitHub and push `main` to it. If you don't know how to do that, GitHub will give you instructions when you create the new remote repo there. If you insist upon the new repo "replacing" the old repo then you can change the names of the repos, but there's really no need; just tell GitHub to delete the old repo once you're satisfied that you've done the right thing, and go right on using the new repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a new repo with only the history you want:

   ```
   git clone --depth=10
   ```
2. Archive the old repo.